# Create a gold look object in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have created a sphere with `MeshPhongMaterial` and add yellow color with emissive, specular and shininess options, but I cannot get a realistic gold look. I want help to make the object look like gold, metallic and shiny, by adding any texture or changing/adding any other options. Thanks

Comment: Use [`THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()`](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=standard#webgl_materials_variations_standard) instead.

Comment: Thank you @prisoner849. Can you guide me alittle bit further to know if I need to use texture with THREE.MeshStandardMaterial() or else.

Comment: Oh I see, you have linked an example, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I could make my sphere metallic, but do I need to change any option or add texture to make it shiny or reflective? Thanks

Comment: You can play around with `.metalness` and `.roughness` parameters. Also you're free to add `.envMap` to make your sphere look more realistic. FIY, we have a [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/).